# c++ accessing string index inside this pointer

Tags: c++, string, this

```
class X
{
 private: 
    string DATA;

. 
.
. 

  const string read_entry( const string & s )   {   return this->(DATA[1]); } //Error


}
```

What's wrong with this? I'm trying to access the index of the DATA string, but I get an error when I do `this->DATA[1]`

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the return type of the function.  The stated type is `const string` but indexing into a `string` returns a `char`.  Try the following instead

```
char read_entry( const string & s )   {   return this->DATA[1]; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in the code snippet:

1. Illegal `()` around `DATA[1]`. Change `return this->(DATA[1]);` to `return this->DATA[1];`.
2. Wrong return type: the type of `DATA[1]` is `char`, not `string`.

Also, add `;` after class definition.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- the return type of your function (const string) does not match the type you are returning (char).  Without knowing the purpose of this function I don't know exactly what fix to make to this.
- you're passing in a string& to your function, but it isn't used in the function body.  What is the purpose of that?
- you don't need the explicit reference to 'this', 'return DATA[1]' is sufficient.
- unless you're very certain about the length of DATA, you should use DATA.at(1) rather than DATA[1], because .at() does a range check for you.  Without this you might be risking memory problems.
- in future, please explain what the code is supposed to do, so we can understand why it looks the way it does.